# What is the purpose of the Dragon Priest Masks?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've found some nice masks and held on to them. But is there any special purpose to the Dragon Priest Masks other than their magical powers?

The masks I'm talking about are:

- Hevnoraak
- Konahrik
- Krosis
- Morokei
- Nahkriin
- Otar
- Rahgot
- Vokun
- Volsung

Comment: @Krazer That's why I didn't sell 'em off... But what I really want to do is put them all in a horadric cube and transmute them into a SUPER MASK!

Comment: Do you think you could fit all those masks in that tiny 4x3 box? >;p That 9th mask is pretty sweet. It has knock back, healing, AND summoning... if you're lucky that is.

Comment: @Krazer Fantastic idea! It must be done!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After collecting the 8 Dragon Priest Masks, and the Wooden Mask, followed by placing the other 8 Dragon Priest Masks on the correct pedestals, you'll be granted a 9th mask, Konahrik.

You can find the [Wooden Mask](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Wooden_Mask) after entering a mounded room, located just outside Labyrinthian, known to some as the Bromjunaar Sanctuary. In the room, you will find the Wooden Mask near some skeletal remains. It's latent power will only work in that room. Put it on and see what it reveals...

Comment: Why would I want to sacrifice Morokei for a crappy Konahrik?

Comment: Now who said anything about sacrificing Morokeis? You get all 9 + 1. It's got tusks, too! And it occasionally summons a friend if you are lonely.

Comment: Maybe add spoiler tags?

Comment: @Annan I reworded the question to make it more obvious that the answer will contain spoilers.

Comment: Heh. It was a reverse spoiler to me. I found the wooden mask *long* before I was capable of killing one of the dragon priests...When I finally killed one, and saw the mask I suddenly knew what I had to do to complete that "quest".

Comment: @Krazer Please elaborate on "occasionally summons a friend". I haven't found anything about this. What do you mean?

Comment: @Coomie On very rare occasions, the mask will summon a spectral Dragon Priest (friend) to come to your aid.

Comment: Has anyone else considered the idea the masks are actually a hidden message? krosis means sorry, or at least seems that way when you speak to parathanax.